# is there a way randomly separate a string into different string array and get back same same string

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, random

For example i have

```
String Text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ";
```

to run through some codes to get into

```
String[] text1 = "AOCN";
String[] text2 = "JQBF";
String[] text3 = "DMG";
String[] text4 = "HPI";
String[] text5 = "KEL";
```

then some code to get it back to

> String Text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ";

is this possible?
what I am trying to achieve is random storing the spilt character into 5 different String Array and use code to revert it back to it original text

Comment: anything is possible

Comment: @GrantWinney have edited the question its suppose to be a string array sorry for the confusion

Comment: @GrantWinney storing it like this is also fine `String[] splitText = new[] { "AOCN", "JQBF", ... };` but i need to be able to get back the original string in the starting position

Comment: Why are you doing this? Is this some sort of encryption scheme? The easiest way to "get the string back" is to simply use the original string. Are you basically asking for reversible randomization? But if it's reversible, and someone knows or can reverse-engineer your algorithm, then it's not secure, unless you use some kind of proper cryptographic method. But if you're doing that, you're WAY better of just using a standard library instead of trying to roll your own...

Comment: If you can 'get back same string' then it is not random, because you know how to do it, whereas randomness is unpredictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the request for a "random" allocation of letters to arrays is for a pseudo-random (or, perhaps, a superficially arbitrary) allocation that is therefore reversible, one technique to do this would be to essentially use a [transposition cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_cipher).

The algorithm would then be something like:

1. Run the transposition cipher on the input text.
2. Split the transposed text into the arrays.

The original text would then be obtained by reversing the two steps.

(EDIT)

The transposition cipher key could consist of a stream of pseudo-random numbers from `1` to `n` where `n` is the number of strings into which the input string is to be split. Thus, an expanded algorithm would read as follows:

1. Generate a list of pseudo-random numbers, `p`, of length `m`, where `m` is the length of the input string.
2. For all `i`, assign the `i`th letter in the input string to the output string number `p[i]`.

To reassemble the original string:

1. For all `i`, obtain the `i`th letter in the string from the next unused letter in string number `p[i]`.

Comment: I have already thought of using some sort of cipher when i first thought of doing this, but thought it might slow down my programme too much so i am leaving this for last possible way

Comment: If the list of pseudo-random numbers was pre-generated, there would be very little computation time involved in retrieving the numbers and using them to assign the characters of the input string. Besides, [premature optimisation is the root of all evil](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth).

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary string, and assuming your distribution is truly random, then unless you somehow stored the randomizing factors there would be no way to reassemble the original string. This reminds me of Write-Only-Memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can iterate character by character :

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const string s = "Hello!";
        // Option 1
        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);           // Your treatment here
        }
        // Option 2
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s[i]);        // Your treatment here
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this to concatenate (treatment porcess) :

```
if (some_condition) text1 += s[i];
```

Then in `Your treatment here` parts you could use basic random functions provided by C#. As long as you do not change the `seed`, you can retrieve the sequence used to generate the substrings and probably revert it...

Could be, by example, something like that :

```
int seed = 12;
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
// Repeat that until you processed the whole string
// At the mean time, skip the characters already indexed
while (lst.Count != s.Length) {
    int n = new Random(seed).Next(0, s.Length); 
    if (!lst.Contains(n)) {
        text1 += s[n];
        lst.Add(n);
    }
}
```

In the end `lst` is your key to revert the process.

Then the way you generate the substring, and the algorithm to restore the original string is up to you too... You are completely free.

**Note :** *Concerning dealing with `chunks`, please refer to `Simon`'s answer.*

Comment: this is not what I wanted to achieve I wanted to randomly store the split character into 5 string array and able to revert it back to its original text

Comment: You can use any kind of algorithms, existing ones, or self-made ones. Feel free...

Comment: i do not understand what is the seed used for

Comment: This is the same as not specifying a `seed` at all, but I used explicitly a constant one to warn you that the series of numbers will always be the same while calling `.Next()` on a new `Random` object. Ex. if the four first calls give [18, 2, 5, 12]. Calling `Next()` four times on a new `Random` object will again be [18, 2, 5, 12]  while keeping the same `seed`. So that you can retrieve your random sequence at any time, even if you didn't store it anywhere. Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ";


        int chunk = new Random().Next(1,Text.Length/2);

        var result= Split(Text,chunk);


        Console.WriteLine("Splited:");

        foreach (var word in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        }


        string toOld = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Returned:");

        toOld = result.Aggregate((i, j) => i + j);

        Console.WriteLine(toOld);

        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    static List<string> Split(string str, int chunkSize)
    {
        var re = Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / chunkSize)
            .Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize)).ToList() ;

        var temp = re.Aggregate((i, j) => i + j);

        if (temp.Length < str.Length)
        {
            var last = re.Last();
            last += str.Substring(temp.Length, str.Length - temp.Length);
            re[re.Count-1] = last;
        }
        return re;

    }
```

you can control chunk size

Comment: the code you have provided is not randomizing the text but just spiting it, what i need is to randomize it and get the same text back