# C# Same name for multiple labels

Tags: c#

I made program to get random word with length between 10 and 12.
How to shuffle random word that I get and split it's letters on 12 labels???

```
string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename= C:\Users\Pavle\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test slagalica\Test slagalica\Slagalica-DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

string queryString = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE LEN(Reci) >=10 AND LEN(Reci) <=12 ORDER BY NEWID()";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        string word = (string)mycommand.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try? We are not a code writing service. Can you create labels? Can you random shuffle? Can you combine them? If not, where are you stuck?

Comment: [Is this close enough?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17182014/993547)

Comment: I created labels but I don't know how to shuffle word and every time I click button it should show letter of word on other lable!!!

Comment: A good shuffling algorithm for this would be the fisher-yates shuffle.  Look it up and have a go at implementing it.

Comment: How to every time I click button show letter of word on other label?

Comment: Loop through the resulting array from your shuffle algorithm and set each letter to a label.

Answer (score 1):

> I created labels but I don't know how to shuffle word and every time I
>   click button it should show letter of word on other lable!!!

```
Random rnd = new Random();
string word = "HelloWorld2016";

var result = word.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();//your word is shuffled

label1.Text = result[0]; //and so on.
```

You can use `Random` and `OrderBy` it.

Comment: How to every time I click button show letter of word on other label?

Comment: I don't understand what is your question.

Comment: If word is "HELLOWORLD" when I first time click button on first label should be "H",when I click second time on second label should be "E" and so on..

Comment: I feel your comments are contradicting your question. Please edit your question as try to explain better what you need. (@mybirthname My vote nonetheless since I think the answer is okay given the question. You might want to elaborate a little more on what the code does.)

Comment: @Pavle_nis you can have property Counter = 0 on first click of the button find label1 and label1.Text = result[counter] and after that increase the counter. On second click find label2 and put again result[counter] and increase the counter.

Comment: When I set label1.Text=word[counter] I get error the name word does not exist in current context!!!

Comment: I made every time I click button to show word letter on each label.But this only works with word that has lenght 12,for words that have lenght 10 and 11 program crashes.What should I do?
If word lenght is 10 it should generate 2 random letters and place it somewhere in word,if word lenght is 11 it should generate 1 random letter and place it somewhere in word!!!